# Radius of convergence of combination of power series

Tags: real-analysis

I am revising for exams and I came across a problem in the notes which the lecturer left as an exercise but I can't figure it out.

I would initially like to show that given $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ has radius of convergence $R_1 > 1$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$ has radius of convergence $R_2 > 1$ then the radius of convergence, $R$ of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nb_nx^n$ is at least $R_1R_2$. I have proved that given $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \beta_n$ converge absolutely then so does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n\beta_n$ but im not sure if this helps.

As a point of information, I have seen a couple of proofs online that use lim sup but we have not used this in class so i would prefer to stay away from this.

Then I will investigate if $R=R_1R_2$ but as yet I have not been able to prove the theorem above.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure you must have studied lim sup and lim inf if you have studied power series, can you think of how a radius of convergence has been defined, and use that?

Comment: Write down [the formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) for each and then use the [properties of $\limsup$ with respect to multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Properties).

Comment: we have $R$ = sup{$\lvert x \rvert : \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert a_nx^n \rvert converges$}

Comment: Definitely don't use any 'ratio test', since series can have infinitely many terms equal to zero. You do that in my class, and that is instant fail of that question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, is there any other way this can be done without using lim sup? I have never encountered this and my professor clearly thinks this is something we should be able to do without learning about that

Comment: I can't understand how come you haven't studied $\;\limsup\,,\,\,\liminf\;$ as power series is usually studied after limits of sequences, after series and etc. Thus, you must have studied subsequences and etc.

Comment: yes I have studied subsequences etc. in previous courses however I have finished this course and the method has not been mentioned - we haven't studied radius of convergence in terms of the lim sup definition, just the definition I stated in a comment above

Comment: Yes, you can prove this without mentioning $\limsup$. Let $|x|=(R_1-\epsilon)(R_2-\epsilon)$. Then $\sum_n|a_nb_nx^n|=\sum_n|a_n|(R_1-\epsilon)^n|b_n|(R_2-\epsilon)^n\leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_n|a_n|^2(R_1-\epsilon)^{2n}+\sum_n|b_n|(R_2-\epsilon)^{2n}\right)$ where we used that $|r||s|\leq \frac{1}{2}(|r|^2+|s|^2)$. Now, since $\sum_n|a_n||x|^n=\sum_n|a_n|(R_1-\epsilon)^n$ converges, to does the sum of their squares. The same for the other series of squares. Therefore the series $\sum_na_nb_nx^n$ has radius at least $(R_1-\epsilon)(R_2-\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: The proof above is only valid for finite $R_1$ and $R_2$. When one of those is infinite write $M>0$ instead of $R_1-\epsilon$ or $R_2-\epsilon$, whichever the case.