# Showing that $R = R_1 R_2$ for a product of power series

Tags: real-analysis

I have proved that if $\sum a_nx^n$ converges absolutely and $\sum b_nx^n$ converges absolutely with radii $R_1 > 1$ and $R_2 > 1$ then $\sum a_nb_nx^n$ converges absolutely to $R \geq R_1R_2$. Now I would like to know if it is true that $R$ is in fact equal to $R_1R_2$

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Note that these sums are from 0 to $\infty$

Comment: This seems related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219807/radius-of-convergence-of-combination-of-power-series, any reason for posting a second question rather than editing your previous one?

Comment: Yes because this question was part of my last one but we mostly concentrated on the first bit of the question so I decided to post another one just about this specific bit. The answers I got here helped me on this part of the question that I didn’t get from my last one so I don’t see that it’s an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the case where $a_n=0$ for odd $n$ and $b_n=0$ for even $n$ you get $a_n b_n=0$ for all $n$. Hence, the series $\sum a_n b_n x^n$ has radius of convergence $R=\infty$, while the radii of $\sum a_n x^n$ and $\sum b_n x^n$ might still be both finite.

Comment: I was thinking letting $a_n = 1+(-1)^n$ and $b_n = 1+(-1)^{n+1}$ but I think this gives $R_1 = R_2 = 1$ which is outside the constraints. Unsure if I could modify this to fit my needs

Comment: If the series $\sum a_n x^n$ has radius of convergence $R$, the series $\sum a'_n x^n$ with $a'_n = 0$ for odd $n$ and $a'_n = a_{n/2}^2$ for even $n$ has the same radius of convergence.

Comment: So if say I used $a_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$ which has radius 2 then $a’_n =  \frac{1}{2^n}$ for even $n$ and $0$ for odds also has radius 2?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $R_1 = \limsup\root n\of|a_n|$.

And the equality is false in general: think what happens when $a_n b_n =0$.